# How to use broadcast receiver to listen to bluetooth pairing request?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to trigger something when receive a pairing request from another android device through bluetooth, I registered the broadcast receiver in my activity but it does not work. Anyone know how to do that?

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
    Log.i("BLE Pairing Info", "111");
    this.registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, filter);
    bluetoothReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice dev = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                Log.i("BLE Pairing Info",action);
                //dev.setPairingConfirmation(true);
            }

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the right permissions?? 
You need Bluetooth Admin permissions to pair/broadcast pairing requests on a device, as you can see:

Check this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_ADMIN

Without that  I guess the system wont send you pairing events either.